# What does the physical structure of InnoDB secondary index pages looks like

Tags: mysql, innodb

According to this https://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/innodb-fil-header.html and did some searching on google. I can see that a record is stored in the user records area on the page with it's `FIL_PAGE_TYPE = FIL_PAGE_INDEX(17855 also 0x45BF).`

But I am now confused about the secondary index. **Did it stored on the same page type with the `FIL_PAGE_TYPE = FIL_PAGE_INDEX`?**

I created a table with some index, added some data. Found that my ibd file contains a `FIL_PAGE_INODE` page. So I am guessing that the secondary index was stored on the page with `FIL_PAGE_TYPE = FIL_PAGE_INODE` .

*If so, How can I found the index content on that page?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Secondary indexes do indeed use `FIL_PAGE_INDEX` just as the primary/clustered key does. There is no structural difference between the primary key and any secondary indexes. The `FIL_PAGE_INODE` page type is part of the space management system, and is described in my blog post on [Page management in InnoDB space files](https://blog.jcole.us/2013/01/04/page-management-in-innodb-space-files/).

Comment: thanks, And one more question: Is it possible to store both primary key and secondary indexes on the same page?

Comment: no, there is an index_id in every page header - the index it belongs to

Comment: @jeremycole as we know secondary index is not necessary unique, that means each key in the index may contains list of values. Now let say, we pick a very poor index (low cardinality), half of tables are mapped to one key in the secondary index. I am curious how one key in the index can hold half of the table size's primary key values. (e.g. if the table contains 10 million records?)

Comment: @Alfred the simple answer is that every entry in a secondary index contains exactly one value. So if there are multiple rows with the same key, they are multiple entries (duplicating the secondary key values), one per row. So in your case if half of a 10M row table contained the value "foo" for a secondary key, the value "foo" would be duplicated 5M times in the index.

Comment: @jeremycole got it. that make a lot sense to me now. Just one more question, do you know how the null values are indexed physically, in case of an indexed column is nullable?

Comment: @Alfred Yes, it's exactly the same for any case, the NULL columns are omitted from the key or value and marked as NULL in the nullable field bitmap. You can see this in the "Secondary indexes" in this post: https://blog.jcole.us/2013/01/10/the-physical-structure-of-records-in-innodb/